# Safari won't connect to any server!

Tags: safari, internet

Chrome & Firefox works fine but when i open Safari it says "Safari can't connect to the server". I have tried to change the DNS and i searched all over google but i couldnt find anything regarding this item.

Can anyone please help me? Even when i watch my webpage on my local server through mamp it says that it cant connect to the server.

Comment: Do you have any plugins?

Comment: yes i do,

Divx Plus Web Player HTML5 is the name of the plugin.

Comment: Check your proxy settings under System Preferences -> Network.

Comment: I looked to my proxy settings but nothing is checked, this is right or wrong?

Comment: Soo... How did you post this?

Comment: through Chrome?..

Comment: Try to disable every plugin you have